# How are composite materials most frequently or most prominently used in satellites and rovers?

Tags: artificial-satellite, materials, rovers, composite-materials

I'd like to understand how [composite materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_material) (CMs) are used on satellites and rovers.

Which parts are made of CMs? If there are numerous examples, then the ones which are particularly large, or where CM achieved some particularly important improvement would be the of interest.

Comment: The [GOCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Field_and_Steady-State_Ocean_Circulation_Explorer) probe was made almost entirely of carbon fibre composite, if I remember correctly. Stiffness was required for the very accurate measurements made on board. (Anyone could check ESA's site directly for the details.)

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a little more attractive to answers. You can revert back by clicking "edited" then "rollback", or make further edits. I think it's a interesting question and hope this helps attract answers.